# Schedule (OpportunityLineItemSchedule) Validation?

Tags: apex, validation, opportunity, opportunity-lineitem

**Anyone know of a magic way to do "Validation" on Schedule items?**

In our example, we want to stop most profiles from touching a Schedule item that has a Schedule Date of "before today" (it's more complicated than that, but that's a good enough example).

With my experience, I default to *"oh, Schedule? forget it"* when asked to do such things usually.  With the lack of Object-level Setup control (custom fields, page layouts, ad nauseum - oh if only we could add ONE PICKLIST to that thing...), it's just a nightmare to deal with the way our company has had to use it.

I decided to bring this here to see if anyone knows of an alternative?  An Apex programmer on our end also doesn't see that he can touch Schedule either.   :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can't validate schedule items in *real time*, there's absolutely nothing prohibiting you from writing a scheduled class that runs hourly and notifies users of their mistake by email (or possibly even by SMS, if you felt up to it). Preferably with an email every hour so they get their inbox cluttered to the point where they'll fix it because they don't want to lose important emails. For bonus points, you could also have it notify their manager, too, on an hourly schedule. ... Well, maybe not hourly, but at least a daily reminder that they screwed up the scheduling.

Comment: Interesting.  So Apex CAN (as would make sense) at least READ the Schedule data.... so your idea makes a lot of sense.  Going to keep this idea handy while continuing my search.  Thanks!

Comment: Also makes sense in the post Dreamforce 2013 world where "there is an API for absolutely everything".  :-P

Comment: @AMM You can do more than just read them; you can also adjust them through updates and delete them, as well. They fully participate in normal Apex Code activities, they just can't be the target of customizations and triggers.

Comment: Accepting this answer as to me it's the "better" one in the long run.  No limitations that might be imposed by VF (especially if certain managed packages are involved that have their own VF - *cough* Rootstock *cough* Financial Force - not directly on LINE ITEM in these cases, but still the same logic).

Answer (score 1):

Can you create a VF page that goes on top of the Schedule?  That way you can write your own custom validations and picklists (SelectOption[])

Comment: The only downside is it's a lot of code, and training users the "right" way to do things, especially if they've been doing something else.

Comment: I certainly can't dismiss this idea (given the limitations yielding few alternatives).  Thanks.